# How to use chart control's assemblies in application without installing it?

Tags: asp.net, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I am using a web application in which there is a chart control. I had installed the Microsoft chart control exe and Visual studio add on.

The problem is that when I upload the application on the server, there is a problem with the two assemblies missing `System.Web.DataVisualization.Design.dll` and `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll`.

So, I want to uninstall the Microsoft chart control exe & Visual studio add on, and instead only use the DLL in the application by giving reference in it.

Now, how do I define chart control on an ASPX page? How do I register the assemblies on the ASPX page and how can I get the chart control from it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just add the DLL's to your Bin directory of your website.

Installing the chart controls locally simply adds the DLL's to your computer somewhere (I think).  And I believe that the Add-In is to give you support for design mode.  It doesn't install anything specific to your projects.

However, you may need to register the controls either on the page or in the web.config.  For example, here is the registration of the AjaxControlToolkit controls in the web.config:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem.

First, add the library `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll` as reference.

Then, add the following line in web.config, inside `<httpHandlers>`

```
<add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
```

You may see `DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler` in red, it will build and run successfully. This may be a ReSharper bug.